# Testing function to get 100% coverage

Tags: go

How would you write a test for the below function to get 100% coverage?

```
func countLines(files []string) int {
  sum := 0
  for _, e := range files {
    f, err := os.Open(e)
    if err != nil {
      fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "err: %v\n", err)
      continue
    }
    sum += countFileLine(f)
    f.Close()
  }
  return sum
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The extremist way

Change the method signature to take as input a `func (string) (os.File, error)` and inject it while doing the tests.

Something along these lines:

```
func countLines(files []string, open func(string) (*os.File, error)) int {
    ...
    f, err := open(e)
    ...
}
```

Then, you can do tests and inject a function that will returns what arrange you for the test.

## The practical way

Simply create files under a `test` directory of your packages, and do you tests using these files.
The upside is that the method is simpler, the tests too. The first method can become quite bothersome when you have a lot of dependencies…

Comment: going with the practical way, how do you test the if err != nil, because it's not returning anything, a solution will be to store all the errors and then return them, but at the moment I don't have a error return, I just write to `os.Stderr` thx btw

Comment: Return a `[]error`, which can be `nil` if you don't have any error.

Comment: By the way, you should probably avoid printing anything except in your main function, be the the real `main` or the function that correspond to you command/subcommand if you use a CLI package.